# Extending native JS objects in Node.js?

Tags: node.js

Is there a node.js way to extend native JS objects, similar to clientside:

```
Date.prototype.tomorrow = function(){
  return this.getTime()+86400000;
}
```

such that

```
var dt = new Date();
dt.tomorrow();
```

works as expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works exactly like in the browser, since Node is built on top of V8 (Google Chrome's engine). Save the following code and run it with Node:

```
Date.prototype.tomorrow = function(){
  return this.getTime()+86400000;
}
var dt = new Date();
console.log(dt.tomorrow());
```

Answer (score 1):

That ought to work. Prototypes are a plain old JavaScript feature, not Node-specific. In fact, this is what [the Sugar library](http://sugarjs.com/) does, but [you should read their notes on this](http://sugarjs.com/native).

Comment: thanks for the ref to Sugar. Any advice on how to do this as a module so that it can be pulled in easily into projects?